# How to associate CloudFront Distribution to Lambda @ Edge using SAM yml template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a requirement wherein I want to deploy a simple lambda@Edge using aws CLI with the package and deploy commands.

I have defined a yml template with required configuration and I could create Lambda Function.
However, I want to associate this with an existing CloudFront distribution, which I am struggling to find out how to do.

Basically, I need yml format to specify distribution id and request type.

My current yml looks like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: Blueprint for returning HTTP redirect implemented in NodeJS.
Resources:
  awsaumuwebredirect:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      CodeUri: .
      Description: Blueprint for returning HTTP redirect implemented in NodeJS.
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 1
      Role: >-
        arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/service-role/CloudFrontLambdaExecutionRole
      Tags:
        'lambda-console:blueprint': cloudfront-http-redirect
```

Comment: Did you able to solve this one ? I have same requirement like yours

Comment: unfortunately no. Apparently, template didn't have this option.